# How to use javascript string.replace

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace:

`The quick fox jumped over "tree"`

with:

`The quick fox jumped over "wall"`

I have tried this:

```
var str = 'The quick fox jumped over "tree"';
          str.replace(/"tree"/g, '"wall"');
```

Replace is not happening. 
Please help

Comment: or see [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp), mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/replace-method-string-javascript) ...

Answer (score 3):

You just need to save your string after you replace it.

```js
var str = 'The quick fox jumped over "tree"'; 
str = str.replace('"tree"', '"wall"');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: we should not answer the question which was asked without doing any efforts or research

Comment: @sumit Sorry about that, i will add the tip in the comments next time.